# Generic method in class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-conversion

My code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private WdmEntities _context;

    public List<T> GetTable<T>()
    {
        List<T> res = new List<T>();
        _context = new DbEntities();

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(tables))
            res = _context.tables.ToList();//error cannot implicitly convert type
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(columns))
            res = _context.columns.ToList();//error cannot implicitly convert type

        return res;
    }

}
```

I have tables and columns types from *EntityModel*

But i got compile error:

```
 cannot implicitly convert type
```

How i must change my code to make it work?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could identify the line with the error

Comment: What is a type of tables and columns?

Comment: you are using generics - you can't assign a value of a different type to a a variable of type `List<T>` - the compiler can't know what type T is, hence the assignment won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method here.

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(tables))
    res = _context.tables.Cast<T>().ToList();
if (typeof(T) == typeof(columns))
    res = _context.columns.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

However this does not look like a good generic method. You will have to change the code when you need to return a list of another type. You should find a way to get the items from context using another generic method. If that's not possible I would suggest ditching the generic method and writing two seperate methods for these types.

Comment: That is, best practice to write each method for each table - public List<tables> GetTables(); public List<columns> GetColumns(); ?

Comment: It depends on your API. If you can have a true generic implementation that's the best. However your current implementation is not really generic.

Comment: true generic implementation, you can sample code for me? I want to learn it.

Comment: Look for a generic repository implementation in Entity Framework. If there was method like `_context.Items<T>()` you wouldn't need all this casting.

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast each item:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private WdmEntities _context;

    public List<T> GetTable<T>()
    {
        List<T> res = new List<T>();
        _context = new DbEntities();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(tables))

            // If the defined entity type is an abstract class or interface
            // while the returned type from the dbcontext really is of your object type
            res = _context.tables.Cast<T>().ToList();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(columns))
            res = _context.columns.Cast<T>().ToList();

        return res;
    }

}
```

Or just the collection:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private WdmEntities _context;

    public List<T> GetTable<T>()
    {
        List<T> res = new List<T>();
        _context = new DbEntities();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(tables))

            //Just casting the returned list, if the entity type is the same as T
            res = (List<T>)_context.tables.ToList();
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(columns))
            res = (List<T>)_context.columns.ToList();

        return res;
    }

}
```

..depending on how your context have been created.

Answer (score 5):

In a line like this:

```
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(tables))
        res = _context.tables.ToList();
```

The compiler does not attempt to understand how this `if` test impacts the rules of assignment; as far as it is concerned, you're trying to assign `List<table>` to a `List<T>`, and that **isn't OK**, as the compiler doesn't trust you that `table` === `T`.

You can *force* it by using a cast:

```
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(tables))
        res = (List<T>)(object)_context.tables.ToList();
```

However, you might want to check if your `_context` has a generic API. For example, in LINQ-to-SQL:

```
res = _context.GetTable<T>().ToList();
```

On an unrelated note: calling `ToList()` on an unfiltered table is usually a very bad thing.

For that reason, it would be preferable to return either `IQueryable<T>`, or the ORM's preferred `IQueryable<T>` wrapper. For example, with LINQ-to-SQL this might be:

```
public Table<T> GetTable<T>()
{
    return ctx.GetTable<T>();
}
```

or with Entity Framework:

```
public DbDet<T> GetTable<T>()
{
    return ctx.Set<T>();
}
```

However, you should also think carefully about the lifetime management of the data-context; in the code in the question, you `new` the data-context - this context is then free-floating and isn't cleaned up in what I would consider an acceptable fashion. You should probably think about lifetime management a lot more.

Comment: i use Entity Framework. You said, that calling ToList() on an unfiltered table is usually a very bad thing. That is before i use ToList() i check on Null my table?

Comment: No, it's because that all rows in the table are returned. Any `.Where()` on the returned result will just be a filter on the list which is located in the memory and not as a part of the SQL query

Comment: @Mikhail as jgauffin notes: calling the `ToList()` at this point forces it to read that entire table (all rows) over the network, creating an in-memory representation. In most cases, you actually only want one row, or a handful of rows. Be **very** wary of calling `ToList()` prematurely. The thing to return here to avoid this would be the `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: how i can write true generic method implementations? please see comments of accept answer. I want to learn it.

Comment: @Mikhail like `Set<T>` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.103).aspx (which, you may note, implements `IQueryable<T>`). I'll edit my answer to show